# how to use a Variable in a value name in uipath

Tags: variables, uipath

I'm new to uipath so forgive me if this is an easy question. I am using Get Text to retrieve some data from a table. I select Save For Later. How would/can I use a variable as part of the values name? Im not sure if it can actually be done, I'm just thinking of what I can do in php but I know uipath is a different beast. I've tried the following code in the "Give your value a name" field but it dosent work.

```
"random text" + variable
```

Lets say I have a variable called "money", I then create another variable but I want the value of the variable "money" to be part of the 2nd variables name...if that makes sense

Comment: can you explain why exactly you need dynamic variable name?

Answer (score 1):

You should first go to the (free) [UiPath Academy](https://academy.uipath.com/), as this is such a basic question, actually.

But anyway to give you something here, let me solve your question.

1. Go to your `Get Text` activity

[image]

2. Rightclick into the `Output value` field

[image]

3. Select `Create variable` and set name to e.g. "test"

[image]

4. Now you can use that variable wherever you want (keep care of the scope for sure)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm aware of how to create a variable, my question is how to set up a new variable where part of it's name is a variable itself, a dynamic value name I guess you'd call it. Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly enough

Comment: But your "random text" + variable should. So what happens for you?